# Lookup Functionality in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lookup

Is there any way I can create a field that mimics a lookup field in Salesforce?

When using the default contact fields in a visualforce, Salesforce injects lots of their own custom styling which I'm struggling to get rid of.

Is there a way I can roll my own lookup field which I can style entirely myself via CSS?

The following code:

```
        <!-- This field is bound to an object in the controller -->            
        <apex:inputField value="{!newCase.ContactId}" styleClass="form-control"  />
```

Produces a span in HTML with a  tag and an  tag which is the clickable magnifying glass logo. How can I apply a seperate CSS class to each of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Link might help you. I have done it once with the help of this.

[Custom Lookup-VF](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/)